# Implement NOT logic (Negative logic) in nagios alarm

Tags: nagios, network-monitoring

I am newbie in network monitoring field and I have just started my work on nagios. So I have some basic doubts related to nagios.

we have a localhost.cfg at `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg`

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       blah-16.10
        service_description             Sample Check
        check_command                   check_http_services!-H mydomain.com -u "/sample_url" --string "foo bar" -t 60
        }
```

My questions:

1.) I know this script checks **"http service"** for the url "**www.mydomain.com/sample_url**" and find the text "**foo bar**" on that web page.
but I do not know the meaning/usage of the options  (**-H, -u, -t 60, --string**)
i have googled but I can not find proper documentation where I can find the meaning of these parameters. Can anyone please suggest some link/urls for this?

2.) I want to implement kind of negative logic in my alarm. For example: I want to raise the alarm only when I find "**status closed**"`string on my web page (**www.mydomain.com/sample_url**)
How can I achieve this in nagios?

Note: During my searching, I found all those examples which worked like "If '*sample string*' **found** within specific time then '**No Alarm**'. If '*sample string*' **not found** in specific time, then only '**Raise Alarm**'".

But i need exact opposite.

Comment: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/check-http/ seems to be the command you need

Comment: thanks... i got the solution for my first question.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/35040/nagios-monitoring-text-on-a-website should have the answer to the second bit

Comment: @PreetSangha do you have any idea for the second question?